# Getting the name of adjacent month's name and year in CLNDR.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, momentjs, clndr.js

I am using CLDNR.js to create a calendar.

On the control section it generally has a template that outputs something like this:

```
Previous        January 2018        Next
```

My requirement is

```
Dec 2016        January 2018        Feb 2018
```

The template for the control section is:

```
<div class="clndr-controls">
  <div class="clndr-control-button clndr-previous-button">
    <span>Prev</span>
  </div>
  <div class="month"><%= month %> <%= year %></div>
  <div class="clndr-control-button clndr-next-button rightalign">
    <span>Next</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not able to try anything yet, the documentation doesn't cover this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the calendar object in your template and create the dates you need. (previous and next months)

Add the following in place of "Previous" and "Next" labels to display the respective months.

```
<div class="clndr-controls">
    <div class="clndr-previous-button">&lsaquo; <%= this.month.subtract(1, "month").format('MMMM YYYY') %></div>
    <div class="month">
        <%= month %> <%= year %>
    </div>
    <div class="clndr-next-button"><%= this.month.add(2, "months").format('MMMM YYYY') %> &rsaquo;</div>
</div>
```

Here's a working fiddle - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nimeshka/zhkf8vt7/)

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly how I wanted it to look like. Awesome.